# fopen() and save as - php

Tags: php

I have this issue, I would like to create a new file, with another name.

For now I have the file CLPRE.txt opened and saving the changes in the same file, I would like to create a new file from the original one like this

> pseudo-code:
>
> $unique= sha1( uniqid(phc) );
>
> $newFile = $unique.CLPRE.txt

The actual code is resumed with this:

```
$myFile = $loja."/CL.xml";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open");
$pre= file_get_contents('CLPRE.txt');
$writeThis = "some text";
fwrite($fh, $pre.$writeThis);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: if you want to clone the file then why don't you use [`copy`](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

> This function is identical to calling fopen(), fwrite() and fclose()
>   successively to write data to a file.
>
> If filename does not exist, the file is created. Otherwise, the
>   existing file is overwritten, unless the FILE_APPEND flag is set.

Answer (score 0):

Umm you're basically doing it already, you just need to do another call and create it via:

```
$new = fopen($unique.'CLPRE.txt', 'w') or die("can't open");
```

then add what you want into it, and close with:

```
fwrite($new , $pre.$writeThis);
fclose($new );
```

Reference to **fopen()** - http://www.decompile.com/cpp/faq/fopen_write_append.htm